# DOI and ISBN for bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I've written a technical book using Bookdown, which is hosted on GitHub and is open access. As an academic, I'd like people to be able to cite the book, and normally that would be done with an ISBN and DOI. However, I'm not sure what is the best way to get hold of these.

Could anyone tell me the best way to go about this? I am not looking for any royalties, and the book will likely be updated every now and then, so I don't see much point in using a self-publishing service like Amazon, or going through a classical publisher like Springer, CRC, etc.

My ideal end scenario would be just to have the book open access online, but so that it can be cited (I mean properly cited, ideally with ISBN and/or DOI). Any ideas?

p.s. apologies if Stack Overflow is not the place for asking this, not sure where else to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a ISBN costs money, and I do not think it will work well for free online only books. However, getting a DOI is free and easy either by publishing the book as a pre-print on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/) without peer review, or using [zenodo](https://zenodo.org/). You can even automatically generate new DOIs for newer versions with [GitHub actions](https://github.com/ivotron/zenodo).

Comment: Also take a look here https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/archiving-a-github-repository/referencing-and-citing-content

Comment: Thanks, Zenodo looks like an interesting option. Why do you say ISBN won't work well for online books though? Just because of the cost, or something else?

Comment: You don't need an ISBN, and it costs you >100USD for every new version depending on the country. One also don't mention the ISBN in academical citations just author, year and doi...